# Google Cloud apache server

Tags: apache, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to set up a VM instance in Google Cloud Hosting and just set up an apache server for it. I followed a tutorial that showed how to overwrite the server's default web page with a blank page that says "Hello World", but I want to overwrite it with my website's index page, which is in my storage bucket. How do I do that?

Comment: Note, that if you have a static website, which doesn't contain any dynamic code that needs to be executed on server-side e.g. written in php (in other words a website which contains only html, css and javascript code), it can be served directly from your google storage bucket and you don't need additional VM, running webserver for that purpose. Consider editing your question and adding a link to the tutorial you followed. It will make your question clearer, showing others the steps you've taken so far. See also the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets?hl=pl).

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your storage bucket to a folder inside your VM with [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using)

You could mount it to this path [1] as an example, so that your web server points directly to the bucket.

[1] /var/www/html